# Migrating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5 produce compile-time error

Tags: migration, .net-5, .net-core-3.1

I have `.netcore 3.1` application and I want to update it to `.net 5.0`
I have the following code

```
public static IAppSettings ConfigureAppSettings(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    void ConfigureSection<Interface, Implementation>(string sectionName)
        where Implementation : Interface, new() where Interface : class
    {
        Implementation configSection = new Implementation();
        configuration.GetSection(sectionName).Bind(configSection);
        services.AddSingleton<Interface>(configSection);
    }
}
```

it was working previously, but after updating to .NET 5 I start seeing this compile-time error

> CS1061 'IConfigurationSection' does not contain a definition for 'Bind' and no accessible extension method 'Bind' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationSection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

1. Is the `Bind` method been removed?
2. There is no mention for the solution to this problem in the [official documentation for the migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.1-5.0)

**My question: What is the alternative to the `Bind` method?**

Comment: Are you sure you need one? .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. `Bind` is an extension method.  You're probably missing a namespace or package

Comment: [Bind is in the same namespace and package it was in 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). Can you post an actual example that reproduces this problem? What packages were used, what `using` statements?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks sir, problem solved

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I installed this [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/) package and the problem solved.

The strange thing is that when I was using `.net-core3.1` I did not need to install it from `Nuget` but after updating to `.net5` I needed to install this package separately.

[image]

Comment: If you created a new project from scratch the proper package references would be included. That's a great way to find out what's wrong - create a new minimal project and check for differences.

Comment: Reason it works in 3.1, is because Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration --version 3.1.11 indirectly takes a dependency on Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.

Hence following command 
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration --version 3.1.11 will automatically install Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 3.1.11.

Comment: @SurenderSinghMalik and this was changed in .NET 5 ? please provide the source, so I will add your comment to the answer, so everyone could benfinit from the information after I will check it.

Comment: @HakanFıstık yes it has very clearly visible in my experiment. Will share the concrete resource/link if i get anything !!

Comment: Worked for me.  I moved my class to another project within the solution and Bind lost definition.  I didn't think to install Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder since I didn't see that installed on the original project.  +1

Answer (score 3):

With **dotnet 6** worked when I installed [Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/)

```
NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions -Version 6.0.0
```

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` is taking a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` [docs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/#dependencies-body-tab).This is the reason that this library is also solving the problem, but not everyone needs this library to solve the problem. This is not the minimum solution.

Comment: @HakanFıstık, `M.E.Configuration.Binder` alone will not work so `M.E.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` is mandatory. I am using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` for a console app. But when using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` we no longer need to explicitly import `M.E.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.`.